# Find the lowest-cost shortest path from one node to another?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

I have a weighted graph G and a pair of nodes s and t. I want to find, of all the paths from s to t with the fewest number of edges, the one that has the lowest total cost. I'm not sure how to do this. Here are my thoughts:

- I am thinking of finding the shortest path and if there are more than one path then i should compare the number of steps of these paths.
- I think I can find the number of steps by setting the weights of all edges to 1 and calculate the distance.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable first guess for a place to start here is Dijkstra's algorithm, which can solve each individual piece of this problem (minimize number of edges, or minimize total length). The challenge is getting it to do both at the same time.

Normally, when talking about shortest paths, we think of paths as having a single cost. However, you could imagine assigning paths two different costs: one cost based purely on the number of edges, and one cost based purely on the weights of those edges. You could then represent the cost of a path as a pair (length, weight), where length is the number of edges in the path and weight is the total weight of all of those edges.

Imagine running Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph with the following modifications. First, instead of tracking a candidate distance to each node in the graph, you track a *pair* of candidate distances to each node: a candidate length and a candidate weight. Second, whenever you need to fetch the lowest-code node, pick the node that has the shortest length (*not* weight). If there's a tie between multiple nodes with the same length, break the tie by choosing the one with the lowest weight. (If you've heard about lexicographical orderings, you could consider this as taking the node whose (length, weight) is lexicographically first). Finally, whenever you update a distance by extending a path by one edge, update both the candidate length and the candidate weight to that node. You can show that this process will compute the best path to each node, where "best" means "of all the paths with the minimum number of edges, the one with the lowest cost."

You could alternatively implement the above technique by modifying all the costs of the edges in the graph. Suppose that the maximum-cost edge in the graph has cost U. Then do the following: Add U+1 to all the costs in the graph, then run Dijkstra's algorithm on the result. The net effect of this is that the shortest path in this new graph will be the one that minimizes the number of edges used. Why? Well, every edge adds U+1 to the cost of the path, and U+1 is greater than the cost of any edge in the graph, so if one path is cheaper than another, it either uses at least one fewer edge, or it uses the same number of edges but has cheaper weights. In fact, you can prove that this approach is essentially identical to the one above using pairs of weights - it's a good exercise!

Overall, both of these approaches will run in the same time as a normal Dijkstra's algorithm (O(m + n log n) with a Fibonacci heap, O(m log n) with another type of heap), which is pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

One node to another would be a shortest-path-algorithm (e.g. Dijkstra).
It depends on your input whether you use a heuristic function to determine the total distance to the goal-node.
If you consider heuristics, you might want to choose A*-search instead. Here you just have to accumulate the weights to each node and add the heuristic value according to it.

If you want to get all paths from any node to any other node, you might consider Kruskal’s or Prim’s algorithm. 
Both to basically the same, incl. pruning.